# make facebook sdk cache user's credentials

Tags: android, facebook, caching

Is there way to make facebook sdk to cache user's login/password? Currently I have to enter my credentials each time I run the app.
I use standard way of logging in with login button.

in my activity:

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton);
    this.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have following code in your `onResume()` or `onCreate()` of your activity

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
if (accessToken!=null) {
         Profile profile=Profile.getCurrentProfile();
         nextActivity(profile);
}else{
         //Launch FB login
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks.Just  realized my question doesn't make much sense.Sdk caches everything  and performs automatic login as soon as it can so I don't need to worry much about it.